# Filtering ui-grid[ng-grid 3.0/or earlier] using range slider

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid, rangeslider, angular-ui-grid

I want to filter a standard ui-grid [ng-Grid 3.0] with range sliders. In the tutorial section I found the from to interval text input filters, but I cannot bind it to angularjs values coming from range sliders. Any ideas?

Alternatively I would (once again) revert my code to ng-Grid < 3.0. Any ideas how to do that here (I got to the point where I can filter multiple columns at once depending on the filteroptions.filtertext.

Answer (score 1):

I found "the" solution:

This works for me: http://plnkr.co/edit/tXDJj81nqbNAS1yLh1KX?p=preview

```
$scope.$watch('from', function(newValue) { 
  $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs[5].filters[0].term = newValue;$scope.gridOptions.columnDefs[5].filter[0].term = newValue;
});

$scope.$watch('to', function(newValue) { 
  $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs[5].filters[1].term = newValue;
});
```

The columnDef index has to be searched manually. In my case the 5th column def looks as follows:

```
{
   field: 'age',
   filters: [{
        condition: uiGridConstants.filter.GREATER_THAN,
        placeholder: 'greater than'
   }, {
        condition: uiGridConstants.filter.LESS_THAN,
        placeholder: 'less than'
   }]
}
```

Important is the fact that the filters have been defined before!

Comment: I found this question as I was digging through the ng-grid source code to see if I could implement range sorting. Thanks.